# Search for text inside all child of a div and hide the ones that doesn't contain it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I would like to hide all the divs that doesn't contain the text i'm writing inside a .

i've tried with something like this:

```
var $searchBox = $('#search-weeazer');
$searchBox.on('input', function() {
    var scope = this;
    var $userDivs = $('.information ');
    if (!scope.value || scope.value === '') {
        $userDivs.show();
        return;
    }
    $userDivs.each(function(i, div) {
        $('div:contains(scope.value)').hide();
    })
});
```

but doesn't work (i know i will hide the div that contains the text, was for testing purpose ^^)

The divs are created dynamically after an Ajax Call, and the structure of the div is this:

```
"<div class=\"row information text-white shadow-lg p-2 mb-2\">" +
        "<div class=\"col-3 profilePicture\">" +
            "<img src=\"../../img/bg-masthead.jpg\" alt=\"Immagine profilo\" class=\"profileImage rounded-circle\">" +
            "<div class=\"results\">" +
                "<div class=\"results-content\">" +
                    "<span class=\"stars\">3</span>" +
                "</div>" +
            "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class=\"col-9 infos\">" +
            "<div class=\"row\">" +
              "<div class=\"col-4 nome\"><b>Nome: </b>" + nome + "</div>" +
              "<div class=\"col-4 regione\"><b>Regione: </b>" + regione + "</div>" +
              "<div class=\"col-4 citta\"><b>Città: </b>" + citta + "</div>" +
            "</div>" +
            "<div class=\"row\">" +
                "<div class=\"col-4 dataNascita\"><b>Data di nascita: </b>" + eta + "</div>" +
                "<div class=\"col-4 coaching\"><b>Coaching online: </b>" + (coaching === "T" ? "Sì" : "No") + "</div>" +
                "<div class=\"col-4 sesso\"><b>Sesso: </b>" + (sesso === "F" ? "Femmina" : "Maschio") + "</div>" +
            "</div>" +
            "<div class=\"row border-bottom\">" +
                "<div class=\"col-6 blurry-text cellulare\"><b>Cellulare: </b>" + cellulare + "</div>" +
                "<div class=\"col-6 blurry-text email\"><b>Email: </b>" + email + "</div>" +
             "</div>" +
            "<div class=\"row descriptionText \">" +
                "<div class='col-10 descrizione'>" + descrizione + "</div>" +
                "<div class='col-2 align-items-center'><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-large profileButton' data-id='" + id + "'>Profilo</button></div>" +
            "</div>" +
            "</div>" +
      "</div>"
```

But the script just does nothing for now. Any suggestion?

Comment: `$('div:contains(scope.value)')` <= "scope.value" is a literal string here.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm having a problem now: 1) How can i hide the one that doesn't contain the text?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/not/  or `:not(...)` as part of the first selector.

Comment: Yeah, that should select any div that does not contain your value, and then hide them

Comment: Perfect! Just last thing and i should be all good! I would like to delete the entire div only if none of the childs contains the text, right now it delete even the childs of the div that does contain the text. How can i achieve something like this?

Comment: That shouldn't be happening.  `:contains()` should return elements so long as they contain the text, be it in them directly or in one of their nested children.

Comment: I think Jack-Bashford and @Taplar answered your question. When you post questions in the future, please be sure to provide enough information to easily create a small demo. For instance your returned AJAX isn't easily recreatable because you haven't provided dummy variables or string replacement. It's REALLY helpful to be able to plug in code and demonstrate an answer. Not just for yourself, but for others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('div:contains(scope.value)')
```

Should be...

```
$('div:contains("'+ scope.value +'")')
```

So the value is appended to the string.  Keep in mind if the value can contain double quotes you would have to escape them.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, you're searching for elements that contain the *literal string* `(scope.value)`. Use concatenation like so:

```
$("div:contains('" + scope.value + "')");
```

Or use a template literal:

```
$(`div:contains('${scope.value}')`);
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help! I'm still having an issue with the code. I've changed it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/hj9r2L4u/6/ the only problem now is that i want to hide the entire div only when there isn't the text inside all the childs of the div, i don't want to hide the childs too. Any help?